# SDL2 window unresponsive despite handling events

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I've tried to visualize the Mandelbrotset utilizing SDL2. For this I've used the following program

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <process.h>

double scale_factor = 1000;
SDL_Window *window = nullptr;
SDL_Renderer *renderer = nullptr;

int is_in_mandelbrot_set(std::complex<double> c)
{
    std::complex<double> z(0, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        z = std::pow(z, 2) + c;
        if (std::norm(z) > 10)
        {
            return i;
        };
    }
    return 0;
}

float lerp(float a, float b, float f)
{
    return (a * (1.0 - f)) + (b * f);
}

int main(int argv, char **args)
{
    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(1000, 1000, 0, &window, &renderer);
    SDL_RenderSetScale(renderer, 2, 2);

     for (double x = 0.0; x < 1.0; x += 1 / scale_factor)
    {
        for (double y = 0.0; y < 1.0; y += 1 / scale_factor)
        {
            double loc_x = lerp(-2.0, 2.0, x);
            double loc_y = lerp(-2.0, 2.0, y);
            int iters = is_in_mandelbrot_set(std::complex<double>(loc_x, loc_y));
            if (iters == 0)
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 255, 255, 255);
                SDL_RenderDrawPointF(renderer, loc_x * 100 + 200, loc_y * 100 + 200);
            }
            else
            {
                SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(
                    renderer,
                    4 * iters % 255,
                    4 * iters % 255,
                    4 * iters % 255,
                    255);
                SDL_RenderDrawPointF(renderer, loc_x * 100 + 200, loc_y * 100 + 200);
            }
        }
    }
    
    bool quit = false;
    while (!quit)
    {
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                quit = true;
                exit;
            }
        }
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    
}
```

The only thing stopping it from going unresponsive is reducing the iterations of the for loops by reducing the variable `scale_factor` to around 200, which makes the result lose a lot of quality. I suppose the event loop simply isn't getting executed during this time, which is why I implemented a new thread, which hasn't helped either.

I am kind of clueless, as the only solution to my problem is supposedly handling events, which I already do.

Comment: `break;` exits the `switch`, you might want to exit the loop.

Comment: *going unresponsive* Do you enable compiler optimizations, do you build the Release config?

Comment: From [SDL_render.h](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/SDL2/include/SDL_render.h#44): *"These functions must be called from the main thread."*

Comment: @Jarod42 Running everything in the main thread still causes the program to become unresponsive.

Comment: @273K Exiting actually kind of worked, where it just went unresponsive got responsive again only to display nothing, it now gets unresponsive but after a while renders everything correctly. 
And no I haven't enabled any compiler optimizations or have tampered with the compiler in any way.
But thanks I got a step further!

Comment: As your image is constant, why recomputing it in loop? i.e. : `draw_Mandelbrot(nullptr); SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); while (!quit) { handleEvent(); }`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Good point. That was an oversight of mine. It didn't fix the issue however.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) in the loop?

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't quite follow how this should help my case if I have to use all render functions in my main thread?

Comment: If you are now running everything in the main thread like you said, then your code has changed. Edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Your new code work fine for me after adding the SDL include and a `return` in `main`. It just takes a while (few seconds for me) to render the picture.

Comment: You should probably render the picture in a `SDL_Surface` using multiple threads, and then render that surface in the main thread.